# Subquery or join to match 2 tables on 2 fields on a range of values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I want for each unique `pur_dates`, how many items from the `product_sold` field was equal to items in `product`field WHERE `chk_date` was within 31 days of the `pur_date` DIVIDE by total number of `product_sold` in that 31 days.

The 2 big conditions are that items in `product_sold` is equal to item in `product` and for the match to be valid, the date range from table2 must be within a month of table1.

The `product` field is unique while the `product_sold` field can have repeating products. The `pur_date` field only varies on year and month.

```
Table1
    pur_date      product
    2015-07-01    shirt
    2015-06-01    shoe
    2015-04-01    purse
    2015-04-01    bag
    2014-05-01    key
    2015-05-01    gloves

Table2
chk_date     cost  product_sold
2015-07-29     9    bag
2015-07-15    10    shoe
2015-06-30     8    shirt
2014-06-25     6    bag
2015-06-01     9    shirt
2015-05-28     8    shoe
2015-05-15     4    key
2015-04-28     5    shirt
2015-03-15     6    purse
2015-03-15     4    ring
2015-03-10     4    key
2015-03-01     2    bag
```

I have a non-working subquery to do something like this:

```
        Select pur_date,
        (Select SUM(CASE WHEN product_sold IN (select product from table1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(product_sold) 
        from table2
        where (pur_date - chk_date) <=31) AS percent_sold 
        from (select distinct pur_date from table1) t;
```

Error i got was: `Illegal expression in WHEN clause of CASE`

Example:

```
output_table
pur_date   num_product_match
2015-07-01    2/3       <--for the 3 product_sold in June,2 items(shirt) match product = shirt
2015-06-01    1/2       <-- for the 2 product_sold in May,1 item(shoe) match product = shoe  
2015-05-01    1/1       <-- for th 1 product_sold in April, 1 item(shirt) match product = shirt
2015-04-01    2/4       <-- for the 4 product sold in March, 2 item(purse, bag) match product = purse and product = bag
```

Comment: The question is unclear... how does it decide which product to use for the top part of the fraction? Where do you indicate what product that is?

Comment: As long as the `product_sold` is a match with the `product` and is within a month ago of the `product`'s `pur_date` , we sum it up. we dont care about what product it is, just the number of matches. The `product` column is unique.

Comment: But clearly more than one product will match. If you have a row that shows `2015-07-01     2/3`, logically you **must** also have another row that shows `2015-07-01     1/3`. But your sample results don't bear this out.  And which product goes with which row? And for your March sample, what is the reason that the query should group purse and bag together?

Comment: Okay, never mind. I see better how the tables match up now. But it's not clear in the question at all.

Comment: I hope its slightly clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pd.pur_date, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN t1.product IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 
    CAST(COUNT(t2.product_sold) as float)  As num_product_match    
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT pur_date FROM Table_1) pd
INNER JOIN Table_2 t2 ON t2.chk_date < pd.pur_date 
    AND t2.chk_date >= DATE_ADD(pd.pur_date, INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
LEFT JOIN Table_1 t1 ON t1.pur_date > t2.chk_date 
    AND t1.pur_date <= DATE_ADD(t2.chk_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
    AND t1.product = t2.product_sold
GROUP BY pd.pur_date
```

Comment: i dont really need the '\' sign in there, i just wanted to explain how i get the value in there. The value should be float so 1/2 is 0.5.

Comment: Edited to use division instead of a string... but I really recommend returning numerator and denominator as separate columns.

Comment: sorry need some help understanding, why do you need to specify t2.chk_date < pd.pur_date when you already mentioned `chk_date >= DATE_ADD(pd.pur_date, INTERVAL -1 MONTH)`. Doesnt the second line already mean within a month before? Instead of that can we use this: `pur_date - chk_date <= 31 And  pur_date - chk_date > 0`?

Comment: No, we can't do that. If you remove the second check you will also match products sold in future months. Also, not all months have 31 days. Use the  standard DATE functions... they're there for a reason.

Comment: in line 8: `AND t2.pur_date <= DATE_ADD(t2.chk_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`  `pur_date` is in `table_1`, is it right that you use t2.pur_date?

Comment: Should be been `t1`. Corrected.